# "You and I will be their friend" vs. "You and I will be their friends."

Tags: grammar

Which is proper? 'Their' is singular.

Comment: This is a problem with using _friend_ as a predicate. The way to get around it is to use the idiom _be friends with_, which is always plural and solves the problem. _You and I will be friends with them_ encompasses all possibilities and is always correct, and so are both _You and I will be friends_ and _You will be friends with me_.

Answer (score 2):

"Friends" is correct, since the subject is plural. "They are (their) friends" or "they are (his) friends". The pronoun is an adjective here and doesn't influence agreement.

You can see this also by the helpful writing practice of flipping the sentence around "their friends are you and I." (Note that "I" is correct here because it is nominative. But some linguists suggest that the I-me distinction is disappearing and even good writers often don't bother with it.)

As @John_Lawler says, most speakers with use an idiom to navigate any ambiguity. But "You and I will be their friend" is also idiomatic, and frequently used to suggest a joint effort to help someone who needs a friend.

Answer (score 1):

"*You* will be their *friend*."  *You* is both singular and plural. Here, it is singular.

"*I* will be their *friend*."  *I* is singular, so you will be just one friend to them.

"*You and I* will be their *friends*."  Notice the plural subject (You and I) and the plural object (friends).

*Their* is a possessive pronoun. Apart from using it to relate to certain people, animals, or things, you could use it to refer to a single person whose sex you do not know or wouldn't specify.